# Como não aplicar opacidade em um elemento filho?

Tags: css, css3, opacity

Eu tenho uma div com opacidade aplicada, porém essa div possui elemento filho. Eu não quero que seja aplicada opacidade a esses elementos filhos, teria alguma maneira de resolver isso?

Exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/1/

Código do link:

```css
.div-pai{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
 .div-filho{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: -75px;
  margin-left: -75px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-pai">
    <div class="div-filho"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acredito não ser possível, porém há *workarounds*.

Se precisar de opacidade apenas no background, é possível aplicar uma cor `rgba`:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/4/). Note que não há suporte para IE<=8.

Caso precise aplicar a opacidade em todo elemento e não somente no background, terás que quebrar a hierarquia e transformá-los em irmãos.

Há uma terceira forma, que funciona caso você esteja buscando um efeito *overlay*. Seria criar um pseudo-elemento `::before` que cobre todo elemento `.div-pai` e fica em baixo do `.div-filho`:

```
.div-pai:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/5/).

Desta forma o `:before` é um irmão da `.div-filho` e fica em baixo desta sem a necessidade de `z-index` devido à ordem dos elementos. Note que a `.div-pai` necessita de um `position` diferente de `static`, não adicionei isto ao código pois a sua `.div-pai` já é `fixed`.
A `.div-filho` também precisa de um `position` diferente de `static` para aparecer sobre o `:before`. Caso contrário, elementos posicionados sempre aparecem sobre elementos estáticos (vide [Empilhamento sem z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)<sup>em inglês</sup>).

---

Quanto a suporte para IE8, é possível utilizar um `.gif`/`.png` com transparência como background, ou aplicar a propriedade `filter` proprietária do IE5-8. Não tive sucesso aplicando o `filter` à um pseudo-elemento, mas funciona se poluirmos a marcação um pouco (adicionando uma `div`).

Para testar no IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/12/show/

```
<div class="div-pai">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="div-filho"></div>
</div>
```

```
.overlay {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    background: white;

    filter: alpha(opacity=30); /* IE5-8 */
    opacity: 0.3; /* IE9+ e todos browsers modernos */
}
```

Ou, sem criar nenhum outro elemento, outra forma que funciona cross-browser (IE8+), utilizando uma imagem como background: http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/17/show

```
.div-pai:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    left: 0; right: 0;

    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABx0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgRmlyZXdvcmtzIENTNXG14zYAAAAWdEVYdENyZWF0aW9uIFRpbWUAMDIvMDMvMTSFgaz/AAAADUlEQVQImWP4//+/LwAJSQNLpIypVwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

Codifiquei a imagem como Data-URI para ficar mais fácil de colocar na resposta, mas não fará diferença linkar para um arquivo `.png`/`.gif` (exceto que geraria uma request extra). Também vou notar que IE<8 não suporta Data-URIs, embora acredito que poucas pessoas ainda se importam com suporte para IE<=7.

Comment: funcionou muito bem as suas sugestões, porém no ie8 eu não obtive sucesso... Seria a unica solução para ie8 uma imagem de background?

Comment: @DenisBernardo sim, um `.gif`/`.png` com transparência funcionaria bem. Dê-me um segundo, é possível utilizar o `filter` do IE também.

Comment: Excelente solução, funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda, já não vou precisar usar imagens... !

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível, a opacidade dos filhos sempre vai ser relativa à dos pais. Se você está precisando mudar apenas a cor do background, poderia em vez de opacity. modificar o atributo background:

```
.div-pai {width: 400px;height: 400px; position: fixed; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nesse caso, aconselharia a usar uma imagem em .png com opacidade como background no elemento pai, uma imagem de 1px por 1px repetindo, fica bem leve, alguns browser mais antigos não dão suporte a essa propriedade.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não é possivel fazer da forma que estás querendo, porém uma sugestão é remover o `div.pai` e apenas utilizar o `div.filho` e colocar uma borda nele, que resultaria na mesma coisa, porém seu elemento filho "central" não ficaria com opacidade, veja o exemplo que fiz no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/8/)

Utilizei do seguinte código CSS:

```css
.div-filho{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    background: blue;
    border: 150px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

E removei o `div.pai` do HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Já passei por caso semelhante, mas a Opacidade no Javascript é sempre herdada pelos elementos, não tem como você remover ela, então o que eu costumo fazer é criar um elemento que fique exatamente na mesma posição e dimensão do elemento que seria o pai com transparência, porém esse elemento não é filho, está após o elemento transparente e contém o que seriam os filhos dele.

O resultado pode ser visto nesse [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSsC3/9/).

Será compatível com todos os browsers e pode ser aplicado a qualquer elemento.

Exemplo:

```
<div class='div_transparente'></div>
<div class='div_opaca_sem_fundo_por_cima_da_div_transparente'>
    <div class='div_filho_opaca_com_preenchimento'></div>
</div>
```

Existem várias soluções para contornar o problema quando é background, mas se sua div, está por cima de uma imagem, vídeo, ou algo do gênero, eu pessoalmente prefiro esta solução, pois é genérica a todos os casos.