# Duvidas sobre CSS aplicar efeito em uma div sem alterar a outra

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte codigo.
A div second esta dentro da div first
Como fazer com que a propriedade opacity não afete a div second

```css
.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.second{

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá! Existe uma  resposta  disponível em outro tópico: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3860/como-n%C3%A3o-aplicar-opacidade-em-um-elemento-filho

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o comentário do nosso amigo @Getulio Rafael Ferreira que disponibilizou o link de uma pergunta semelhante. Você pode fazer o uso do  `background-color: rgba(250,0,0,0.6);` que trara o efeito que você deseja.

Link da resposta semelhante: [Como não aplicar opacidade em um elemento filho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3860/como-n%C3%A3o-aplicar-opacidade-em-um-elemento-filho)

```css
.first {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  background-color: rgba(250,0,0,0.6);
}
.second{

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
  </div>
</div>
```